# PySide - How to reset the CentralWidget after closing of a widget using QStackedWidget

Tags: pyside, qstackedwidget

I'm using a QTabWidget for some postprocessing.
Initially, the content of the tab is a button to open a txt file. Once this button is clicked, the content of the tab changes and a plot is made based on the data inside the txt file. In addition, there is a button to close the plot.

With QStackedWidget, the "openFileWidget" is a CentralWidget, which is replaced by the "newWindow" widget after opening the txt file. If I close the "newWindow" widget, I get back to the (empty) tab.
If I want to have the "openFileWidget" re-appear, what is the best way to do so? As the newWindow is closed, is it still necessary to use `takeAt`?

```
import os, sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MainStartTabWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainStartTabWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        tabWidget.addTab(tab1Tab(), self.tr("tab 1"))

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(tabWidget)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)


class tab1Tab(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(tab1Tab, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initTab1Content()

    def initTab1Content(self):
        self.centralOpenFile = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralOpenFile)
        widgetOpenFile = openFileWidget(self)
        widgetOpenFile.openFileButton.clicked.connect(self.setOpenFile)
        widgetOpenFile.openFileButton.clicked.connect(self.FileOpened)
        self.centralOpenFile.addWidget(widgetOpenFile)

    def FileOpened(self):
        FileOpened_widget = newWindow(self.path)
        self.centralOpenFile.addWidget(FileOpened_widget)
        self.centralOpenFile.setCurrentWidget(FileOpened_widget)

    def setOpenFile(self):
        options = QtGui.QFileDialog.Options()
        fileChoice = "txt (*.txt)"
        self.path, filtr = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "", fileChoice, "", options)

        return self.path


class openFileWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(openFileWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.openFileButton = QtGui.QPushButton("click to open")
        self.openFileButton.setFixedSize(150,150)
        layoutNoFileYet = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layoutNoFileYet.addWidget(self.openFileButton, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layoutNoFileYet)


class newWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, PathToPlanFile, parent=None):
        super(newWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.createFrameUI()

    def createFrameUI(self):
        self.frameUI = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.buttonClose = QtGui.QPushButton("close")
        self.buttonClose.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("plot based on openend file")

        layoutFileLoaded = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layoutFileLoaded.addWidget(self.buttonClose, 1, 1)
        layoutFileLoaded.addWidget(self.label, 2, 1)

        self.frameUI.setLayout(layoutFileLoaded)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frameUI)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    testPlot = MainStartTabWindow()
    testPlot.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your approach entirely. You only want one QMainWindow. There is no need for the openFileWidget; it is just a button. The next thing I would do is simply create a custom QTabWidget editing the addTab to open a file.

```
import os, sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.main_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        self.main_widget.addTab(Page1(), "Tab 1")
        self.main_widget.addTab(Page2(), "Tab 2")
        self.main_widget.addTab(Page3(), "Tab 3")
        self.main_widget.addTab(Page4(), "Tab 4")

        self.main_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)
    # end Constructor
# end MainWindow

class Page1(QtGui.QWidget):
    """First page to display."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        # Widgets
        self.hlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.read_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Open File")
        self.clear_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Clear Data")

        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.read_btn)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.clear_btn)

        # Display data here
        self.display = DisplayWidget("plot based on openend file")

        # Properties
        self.data = None

        # Signals
        self.read_btn.clicked.connect(self.read_file)
        self.clear_btn.clicked.connect(self.display.clearData)

        # Layout
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.hlayout)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.display)
    # end Constructor

    def read_file(self, path=""):
        """Read file dialog."""
        if path == "":
            options = QtGui.QFileDialog.Options()
            fileChoice = "txt (*.txt)"
            path, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "",
                                                             fileChoice, "", options)

        # Cancel button was pressed
        if path == "":
            return


        with open(path, "r") as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
        # close file

        self.display.setData(lines)
    # end read_file

    def set_data(self, data=None):
        """Set the data to display here."""

    # end set_data
# end class Page1

class DisplayWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text=""):
        super().__init__()

        # Layout
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        # Widgets Have all of your display stuff here
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(text)

        # Properties
        self.data = None

        # Add Layout
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label)
    # end Constructor

    def setData(self, data):
        """Set the data to show the plot."""
        self.data = data

        # Plot stuff here
        self.label.setText(str(data))
    # end setValue

    def clearData(self):
        """Clear the plot data."""
        self.data = None

        # Clear data here
        self.label.setText("Open a file to display data")
    # end clearData
# end class DisplayWidget

class Page2(QtGui.QWidget): 
    pass
# end class Page2

class Page3(QtGui.QWidget):
    pass
# end class Page3

class Page4(QtGui.QWidget):
    pass
# end class Page4


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    testPlot = MainWindow()
    testPlot.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would not let the user close the tab. Just have them be able to clear and reload the data if they wish. If you really want them to close then have the clear data button close the displaywidget and have the read file button create a new widget every time. I don't think you need to create a new widget every time. If you don't like the tabs you may want to look into the QToolBox.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer and detailed help Justin!
It is true that my approach is probably overcomplicated. But what I want to achieve is to have an application with 3-4 tabs, of which each tab has its own functionality. So basically each tab is kind of a Mainwindow with different functionalities, and I want to be able to (re)use a given tab each time I reload some data. 
That is why I started with the QStackedWidgets.

Comment: I edited the answer. If that is the case then don't offer a close button. Just clear the data. If you do close then you will have to recreate the widget every time you read a file in. If you do close it then store the data that you have read in, so you can reload the data if needed. Try to nest the items that change inside of the DisplayWidget.